# How to pause the slider image by mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, hover, slider

I have a simple HTML with `li` (image) and I want to create a slider which when I hover the mouse on pictures the slide will pause and when mouse out sliding will continue. I am using this code http://codepen.io/andyunleash/pen/vzGjq

Do you know how to pause the slider by hover mouse?

HTML:

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/800/300" alt="Placeholder"></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="Placeholder"></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/300" alt="Placeholder"></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function unleashSlider(container) {

    var element = container;

    var interval = 1000;

    var fadeTime = 500;

    slideOut(element);

    function slideOut(element, looping) { // slideOut Functionality

        if(looping != null) { // if looping already
            $slide = element; // $slide = the next slide
        } else { // otherwise the slide to fade out is the first child of the container
            $slide = $(element).find(">:first-child");
        }

        // grab the slide, delay using interval, then fade out
        $slide
            .delay(interval)
            .fadeOut(fadeTime, slideIn);

        // once faded out, callback to SlideIn for next slide

    }

    function slideIn() {
        var $nextSlide = $(this).next(); // get next slide

        if ($nextSlide.length == 0) { // if end of slides

            $firstSlide = $(this).parent().find(">:first-child"); // "next slide" return to first child of the slideshow

            $firstSlide.fadeIn(fadeTime); // fade in the original slide

            slideOut($firstSlide, true); // now run the slideOut again

        } else {
            // if there is a next slide
            $nextSlide.fadeIn(fadeTime); // fade it in

            slideOut($nextSlide, true); // then run the fadeOut

        }
    }
}
```